# LINQ query fitting into a model

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model Version.  This houses the information to contain one unique version of a document.

In my view model I set it up like so:

```
public virtual ICollection<IPACS_Version> rejectionList { get; set; }
```

So I can now have a collection of Version documents.

Here is the LINQ:

```
model.rejectionList = (from v in db.IPACS_Version
                        join d in db.IPACS_Document
                        on v.documentID equals d.documentID
                        where v.dateRejected != null && (d.createdBy == currUser || d.requester == currUser)
                        select v);
```

This is giving me the following error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The line can return to me 0 to many "versions".  So what I think I am not understanding correctly is how come this LINQ query cannot fit into my Version model, since the query returns 0 to many versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ query returns `IQueryable<T>`, while you demand it to be of type `ICollection<T>`. These two interfaces are very distinct and you need to bring them into one nature. To say technically, you need to materialize `IQueryable<T>` into some sort of in-memory sequence of data, which would allow add and removal of it's members (nature of ICollection interface abstraction)

Quick solution is to add `ToList` in the end of the query

```
model.rejectionList = (from v in db.IPACS_Version
                        join d in db.IPACS_Document
                        on v.documentID equals d.documentID
                        where v.dateRejected != null && (d.createdBy == currUser || d.requester == currUser)
                        select v).ToList();
```

since [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) implements `ICollection<T>`, this should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Define your property as `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public virtual IEnumerable<IPACS_Version> rejectionList { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is this better than ToList()?

Comment: Yes, since you don't have to iterate. Instead you can defer it until you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change your view model to use `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `ICollection<T>`, then the easiest way to solve your issue is to call `ToList` on the final query. `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Is one better than the other?

Comment: @JamesWilson - One isn't necessarily better than the other. It all depends on what your needs are and how your code works. It'd be impossible for me to judge without knowing the details. Generally, though, if `IEnumerable<T>` meets your needs, use it. Also, you have to think about your data context. If you use `IEnumerable<T>`, you may run into the situation where your context is disposed before the results are fetched.

Comment: @JustinNiessner one more pragmatic question - do you practice assignment of `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`? IQueryable usually means some remote, non-material data, which is out of local memory. If you reference it via IEnumerable and expose it to public API, you're fooling your clients in some sense.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov - If I'm exposing it to a public API, then no. I'll make sure the data is fully fetched so it's properly available to the caller.

Comment: ok, I just had some issues, when this caused problems even without public API. For example, in three layered architecture you expose IEnumerable to Business Logic from DAL (which isn't quite public API), but behind the scenes you pass non-materialized sequence of data. This caused some huge problems and design issues. We agreed as rule to pass behind IEnumerable *only* materialized data.